# Need help installing Ubuntu Budgie onto USB (details in description)

Tags: grub2, partitioning, uefi, usb-installation

I have been trying to do a full install of budgie onto a 32 GB flash drive. At first I was trying to install to one partition the full size of the drive, mount point / , and grub2 would fail to install, which would fail the entire process. Then i found a thread about creating a efi partition for the bootloader to install to, at least 100 MiB, FAT32 before the other partition, mount point /dev/efi. After creating this second partition, Budgie appeared to install properly, but it would not boot, on either of my two machines. My lenovo (personal laptop) said it couldn't find anything to boot, and my hp (school granted machine) couldnt find anything either, and deaulted to booting windows enterprise like normal. What do I need to do? If you need clarification please ask, I am sure this is hard to understand. How do I do a full install of Ubuntu Budgie onto my 32 GB flash drive?

Comment: is the machine booting EFI? the munt point for the efi partition is /boot/efi/. for external media EFI systems look for /efi/boot/bootx64.efi, this is the default media path and is used for all external booting including CD/DVD. you will likely need to copy /boot/ubuntu/grubx64.efi, rename it, and move it to /efiboot/

Comment: ** correction ---  /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi is the file that needs to be copied, renamed, and moved to /efi/boot/bootx64.efi ----  Note paths are relative to the EFI partition not linux rioot

Comment: Try the same via mkusb: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/gui

Comment: @Aravind Isn't that software to create a live usb to use for installation, because I already have that. I am trying to do a full install from a live usb, to anoter usb.